# what does repr(struct.pack('L' , s)) means?

Tags: python

i wanna know what exactly this code does?

```
python -c "import sys , struct ; s=int(sys.stdin.read(),16); print '0x%08x: %s' % (s,repr(struct.pack('L' , s)))"
```

and what pack() and repr() functions exactly do?

Note: `s` is something like 080483db => address of memory

Answer (score 1):

From `help(struct.pack)` and `help(repr)`:

```
repr(...)
    repr(object) -> string

    Return the canonical string representation of the object.
    For most object types, eval(repr(object)) == object.

pack(...)
    Return string containing values v1, v2, ... packed according to fmt.
```

`repr` is pretty commonly used in Python.

The line prints the numbers you typed in, but as the values of bytes. So if you give it `4141414141414141` it will spit out `0x4141414141414141: 'AAAAAAAA'`.